# django: filter based on values

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I need to take a set of values, in this case the foreign key liquorID in LiquorInStore obtained with values() or values_list() and use them to filter the results by ID of it's parent db, Liquor and return those to the webpage.

This is the view, I fear I may not be using the variables correctly.

```
def store(request, store_id=1):
    a = Store.objects.get(StoreID=store_id) 
    b = LiquorInStore.objects.filter(storeID__exact=a).values('liquorID')
    args = {}

    args['liquors'] = Liquor.objects.filter(id__exact=b)
    args['a'] = a

    return render(request, 'store.html', args)
```

Here is the models file as well in case that helps.

```
class LiquorInStore(models.Model):
    StoreLiquorID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    liquorID = models.ForeignKey(Liquor)
    storeID = models.ForeignKey(Store)
    StorePrice = models.DecimalField('Store Price', max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
b = LiquorInStore.objects.filter(storeID__id=a.id).values_list('liquorID', flat=True)
args['liquors'] = Liquor.objects.filter(id__in=b)
```

Comment: I literally just came up wit the same solution and was about to post it. Thanks.